# The emulator is unable to create the external network switches for Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Tags: visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

After a Windows 10 update, all of my Android emulators gave me this error on startup:

> The emulator is unable to create the external network switches:
>
> Something happened while creating a switch: Failed while creating a virtual Ethernet switch.
>
> Ethernet port '{...}' bind failed: The requested resource is in use. (0x800700AA).
>
> The virtual switch cannot be bound to the wireless adapter because the network bridge is already in use. You can configure at most one virtual switch to be connected to a wireless adapter.

Answer (score 2):

If this problem happens on Windows 10, there's an easy fix... navigate to:

- Start Menu
- Settings
- Network and Internet
- Status
- Network Reset

This cleans up all of the virtual network adapters so they can be recreated by the emulator. Once you reboot, delete the emulator and then recreate it and it should create the necessary network adapters in such a way that it will work.

Others have reported that you can just go to Hyper-V and create a new switch manually, but that did not work for me. Also, others have noted that you can go to Device Manager and show hidden devices and delete them to fix this, but that created more problems than it solved for me. This solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this was your solution, but I just had this issue and after failures to find a solution, on a whim in Network Connections I noticed wifi was enabled but not connected since I was hardwired in.   After disabling wifi the emulator reverted back to using the hardwired land connection instead and worked without producing the error you described any longer

Comment: This worked for me - disable all physical network connections (ethernet or wireless) that are not actually being used